# bash script problem, find , mv tilde files created by gedit

Tags: find, mv, tilde

im using linux with gedit which has the wonderful habit of creating a temp file with a tilde at the end for every file I edit.

im trying to move all of these files at once to a different folder using the following:

```
find . -iname “*.php~” -exec mv {} /mydir \;
```

However, its now giving me syntax errors, as if it were searching through each file and trying to move the piece of text. I just want to move all of the files ending in .php~ to another directory. Any idea how I do that?

Cheers Ke

Comment: -iname ? is that a typo? Other than that it works fine for me (using -name rather than -iname)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one-liner:

```
for D in `find . -iname "*.php~"`; do mv ${D} /mydir; done
```

For future reference, if you go into Edit > Preferences > Editor Tab, there is checkbox for "Create a backup copy of files before saving"  That is the guy responsible for creating the tilde version.

Comment: cool, thanks for this, is there any way I can preserve the file structure of those files? its asking me to replace. Also im sure i used to be able to view these hidden files in nautilus but for some reason its not showing them anymore, would love to find out how to show them , thx again :)

Comment: Sorry, off the top of my head I am not sure the way to preserve the structure.

Comment: you can just use `find` with `-exec`. Moreover this will fail on files with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

GNU find

```
find . -iname "*.php~" -exec mv "{}" /mydir +;
```

or

```
for file in *.php~
do
 echo mv "$file" /mydir
done
```